# How to Create Pivot in MS Access to avoid null values for one type of record?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

Can anyone please help me in creating the below pivot table in MS-Access.

Data table

```
    value | Rank | Type
    1.5   |  5   | alpha
    2.4   |  4   | alpha
    3.6   |  3   | alpha
    4.63  |  2   | alpha
    5.36  |  1   | alpha
```

Required Pivot is

```
    Type | 5  | 4  | 3  | 2   | 1
    alpha|1.5 |2.4 |3.6 |4.63 |5.36
```

I have tried the below query

```
    TRANSFORM [Value]
    SELECT [Type]
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY [Type], [Value]
    PIVOT [Rank];
```

and getting resultset as

```
Type | 1  | 2  | 3 | 4 | 5 
alpha|    |    |   |   |1.5
alpha|    |    |   |2.4|
alpha|    |    |3.6|   |
alpha|    |4.63|   |   |
alpha|5.36|    |   |   |
```

Could anyone please help me in updating this query to get the required result.

Thanks a ton.
Honey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all "alpha" values in one row, you must remove `Value` from the GROUP BY section.

Then you need an aggregation function for it - if you are sure to have only one value per rank, `First()` does the job.

To get the 5-4-3-2-1 order, add an ORDER BY clause.

```sql
TRANSFORM First([Value])
SELECT [Type]
FROM tPivot
GROUP BY [Type]
ORDER BY [Rank] DESC
PIVOT [Rank];
```

Edit: it works for multiple `Type`s

```
+-------+-----+-----+-----+------+------+
| Type  |  5  |  4  |  3  |  2   |  1   |
+-------+-----+-----+-----+------+------+
| alpha | 1,5 | 2,4 | 3,6 |      | 5,36 |
| beta  | 999 |     |     | 4,63 |   66 |
+-------+-----+-----+-----+------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Andre. :)

Comment: What if we have two types. say for 3 ranks type is alpha and for 2 ranks type is beta. Would same query work?

Comment: @honey: Please don't do this. I follow the ms-access tag. I will see your question if I have time, and I won't answer if I don't :)

Comment: Andre - i found the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #A
    (

 value NUMERIC(22,6), Rank INT, Type VARCHAR(10)
 )
 INSERT INTO #A VALUES 
 (1.5, 5,'alpha'),
    (2.4,4,'alpha'),
    (3.6,3,'alpha'),
    (4.63,2,'alpha'),
    (5.36,1,'alpha')


SELECT [5],[4],[3],[2],[1]
FROM
  (select value,RANK,TYPE from #A ) AS     SourceTable
PIVOT
(
MAX(value)
FOR RANK IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])
) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: This is giving syntax error. because PivotTable works with Transform keyword in MS-Access (as per my understanding).